# Firebase for Unity3d Windows App

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase

I have been trying to figure out the best way to implement dynamic photos and voice notes into my Unity3d app, and am looking for guidance about the correct backend/database to use.  There would be two apps, one that a user would login to and upload content: I am working with someone that can build an Android app that allows for a user to login with Google, Facebook, etc and upload content (images, messages, etc) to their profile using Firebase.  The other half would be the Windows Oculus Rift app.

I am building a Unity VR experience for Oculus Rift that needs to use this user content dynamically during runtime, but I am not sure the best way to connect Unity with Firebase.  I am aware of the recent Firebase SDK for Unity, but the examples show use cases for Android and IOS builds from Unity, whereas I would need to build to Windows for use with the Oculus Rift.  Will the Unity Firebase SDK work for Windows and if not, are there any suggestions about the best way to accomplish my goal?

Thank you, 
Jacob

Comment: The Unity Firebase SDK does not currently support Windows releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the Firebase Unity SDK only works on Android and iOS. There is nothing on the road map to implement desktop apps in Unity at present.

Note that you can still interact with the Firebase Database using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).